# how to add coordinates in the segmentation of the watershed?

Tags: java, android, opencv, kotlin, image-processing

I am developing an application that removes the background of images according to the coordinates drawn on the screen by the user. The user draws a rectangle around the image of interest. With this I use watershed to segment the image and remove the background from the image. However, I'm having trouble inserting the coordinates in the algorithm so that the entire background is removed. In the image below I select only 4 coins, after segmentation, I want only those 4 coins to remain in the image and the others disappear. However, this is not what is happening. Can someone help me do this removal segment based on the region passed by the user?

[image]

Code:

```
    typealias Coordinates = Pair<Point, Point>    
    private fun extractForegroundFromBackground(coordinates: Coordinates){
    // TODO: Provide complex object that has both path and extension

    val width: Int
    val height: Int
    val rect = Rect(coordinates.first, coordinates.second)
    width = bitmap.getWidth()
    height = bitmap.getHeight()
    val rgba = Mat()
    val gray_mat = Mat()
    val threeChannel = Mat()

    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, gray_mat)

    Imgproc.cvtColor(gray_mat, rgba, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)

    Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, threeChannel, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    Imgproc.threshold(threeChannel, threeChannel, 100.0, 255.0, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU)

    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(threeChannel, threeChannel, Size(5.0,5.0), 0.0)
    val edges = Mat()
    Imgproc.Canny(threeChannel, edges, 50.0, 200.0)
    val contours: List<MatOfPoint> = ArrayList()
    val hierarchy = Mat()
    Imgproc.findContours(edges, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    val fg = Mat(rgba.size(), CvType.CV_8U)
    Imgproc.erode(threeChannel, fg, Mat(), Point(-1.0, -1.0), 2)

    val bg = Mat(rgba.size(), CvType.CV_8U)
    Imgproc.dilate(threeChannel, bg, Mat(), Point(-1.0, -1.0), 3)
    Imgproc.threshold(bg, bg, 1.0, 127.0, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    val markers = Mat(rect.size(), CvType.CV_8U, Scalar(0.0))

    val frame = Mat()
    val rectImage = Mat(rgba.size(), CvType.CV_8U)
    Imgproc.rectangle(rectImage, coordinates.first, coordinates.second, Scalar(255.0, 255.0, 255.0), FILLED)
    Log.i("teste,", coordinates.first.toString() + "\n"+ coordinates.second.toString())
    Core.add(fg, bg, markers, rectImage)

    // Start the WaterShed Segmentation :
    val marker_tempo = Mat()
    markers.convertTo(marker_tempo, CvType.CV_32S)

    Imgproc.watershed(rgba, marker_tempo)
    marker_tempo.convertTo(markers, CvType.CV_8U)

    result_Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)

    Imgproc.applyColorMap(markers, markers, COLORMAP_BONE)
    Utils.matToBitmap(markers, result_Bitmap)

    image.setImageBitmap(result_Bitmap)

    return currentPhotoPath
}
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Can you please attach sample input and expected output ?

Comment: @ZdaR I updated the question with the expected output. can you help me? I need to do this for weeks and I was unable to pass the coordinates so that the watershed can segment from those coordinates and remove the entire background from the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest way is to add `mask` parameter into [add](https://docs.opencv.org/master/javadoc/org/opencv/core/Core.html#add(org.opencv.core.Mat,org.opencv.core.Mat,org.opencv.core.Mat,org.opencv.core.Mat)) method. You will need to create [image of rectangle](https://docs.opencv.org/master/javadoc/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#rectangle(org.opencv.core.Mat,org.opencv.core.Point,org.opencv.core.Point,org.opencv.core.Scalar,int)) `rect` for this to work. Use thickness = [FILLED](https://docs.opencv.org/master/javadoc/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#FILLED) to draw filled rectangle.

```
val rectImage = Mat(rgba.size(), CvType.CV_8U)
Imgproc.rectangle(rectImage, coordinates, Scalar(255, 255, 255), Imgproc.FILLED)

Core.add(fg, bg, markers, rectImage)
```

---

#### Other options

You can multiply `markers` image pixel-wise by image of rectangle. Only pixels of coins that are inside of the rectangle will remain.

However, in this case you need to ensure that the images you're multiplying have range of [0, 1], but your images are in range [0, 255]. So, in order for this to work, just [divide](https://docs.opencv.org/master/javadoc/org/opencv/core/Core.html#divide(org.opencv.core.Mat,org.opencv.core.Scalar,org.opencv.core.Mat)) images by 255, then [multiply](https://docs.opencv.org/master/javadoc/org/opencv/core/Core.html#multiply(org.opencv.core.Mat,org.opencv.core.Mat,org.opencv.core.Mat)) them and finally [multiply](https://docs.opencv.org/master/javadoc/org/opencv/core/Core.html#multiply(org.opencv.core.Mat,org.opencv.core.Scalar,org.opencv.core.Mat)) the result by 255. There is also method [multiply​(Mat src1, Mat src2, Mat dst, double scale)](https://docs.opencv.org/master/javadoc/org/opencv/core/Core.html#multiply(org.opencv.core.Mat,org.opencv.core.Mat,org.opencv.core.Mat,double)) that can multiply the matrices and then multiply the result by 255 at once.

Another way is to use [bitwise and](https://docs.opencv.org/master/javadoc/org/opencv/core/Core.html#bitwise_and(org.opencv.core.Mat,org.opencv.core.Mat,org.opencv.core.Mat)) operation. In that case you need not to convert to range [0, 1].

```
val rectImage = Mat(rgba.size(), CvType.CV_8U)
Imgproc.rectangle(rectImage, coordinates, Scalar(255, 255, 255), Imgproc.FILLED)

val clippedMarkers = Mat(rgba.size(), CvType.CV_8U)
Core.bitwise_and(markers, rectImage, clippedMarkers)
```

One more option is to use [copyTo​](https://docs.opencv.org/master/javadoc/org/opencv/core/Core.html#copyTo(org.opencv.core.Mat,org.opencv.core.Mat,org.opencv.core.Mat)) method. It takes mask as the third parameter.

```
val rectImage = Mat(rgba.size(), CvType.CV_8U)
Imgproc.rectangle(rectImage, coordinates, Scalar(255, 255, 255), Imgproc.FILLED)

val clippedMarkers = Mat(rgba.size(), CvType.CV_8U)
Core.copyTo(markers, clippedMarkers, rectImage)
```

Comment: can you help me do this in the code, please do not know how it is. I did as you suggested and the result is in the question I updated.

Comment: It seems that I put the wrong argument into Imgproc.rectangle. It should be `rectImage` instead of `frame`. Fixed this in my answer

Comment: By the way you can output rectImage in order to debug your program, to see if the rectangle is rendered correctly.

Comment: This is taking correctly ... I used the log and it gives me the coordinates of the demarcated region.

Comment: So, did you replace `frame` by `rectImage` and result remained the same, right? Did you try other solutions (using `bitwise_and` and `copyTo`)?

Comment: bitwise_and OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and type), nor 'array op scalar', nor. copyTo error Unresolved reference: copyTo.

Comment: It worked. Now how do I make coins appear in the place of that mask?  I update the question with the code

Comment: You can take original image of the coins and use `markers` as a mask for it, for example by using copyTo function. You just need to ensure that the mask has zero values for background and non-zero values for coins.